# Special "My Contacts" group in Android contacts

Tags: android, android-contacts

In Android, when the People app displays the contacts for a Google account, by default it shows only the contacts that belong to the *My Contacts* and *Starred in Android* groups.

I would like to display this same subset of contacts, since the full contact list includes a lot of fluff. This can be donde by [testing group membership](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.html) for each contact; this obviously requires kowing the desired group ids.

The question is: **how can these "apparently special" groups be identified?** Are their ids or names fixed? (They are 1 and 2 for the "primary" Gmail account in the devices I've tested, but I doubt this is reliable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [source code for the Contacts app](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Contacts/+/master) (and in particular at the [`ContactLoader`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/ContactsCommon/+/master/src/com/android/contacts/common/model/ContactLoader.java) class in the ContactsCommon project), these groups can be identified by information in the Groups table. In particular:

- [`AUTO_ADD`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.GroupsColumns.html#AUTO_ADD) == 1 for the *Default* (My Contacts) group.
- [`FAVORITES`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.GroupsColumns.html#FAVORITES) == 1 for the *Favorites* (Starred in Android) group.

However, both these fields are available only on API level 11+.